# yahoo finance API, how to get/parse AAPL+Analyst+Opinion in csv or JSON

Tags: java, rest, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

problem is what I want to get information from

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ao?s=AAPL+Analyst+Opinion  link , where are tables Analyst Opinion,

Upgrades & Downgrades History,Recommendation Trends. Are they available via

link   http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+Analyst+Opinion&f=nkqwxyr1l9t5p4 ?

It was return table like

```
Apple Inc.  575.14  6-Feb   385.10 - 575.14 NasdaqNM    2.33    13-Feb  519.61  N/A -0.74%
ANALYST N/A N/A N/A - N/A   N/A N/A N/A 0   N/A 0.00%
OPINION N/A N/A N/A - N/A   N/A N/A N/A 0   N/A 0.00%
```

I am interested to get information like Buy, Sell , Hold .

Which type of query  I need to make?